# How to redeem a delta voucher on already booked upcoming trip

Tags: delta-air-lines

I have a e-voucher from Delta airlines. One of my friend has booked a trip from detla which includes me too. How can I now redeem my e-voucher on the already booked trip?

Comment: If the flight was booked less than 24 hours ago, and is at least 7 days away, your friend can cancel it right now for a full refund. You can then book it again using your voucher. Otherwise, I'm not sure it's possible to apply a voucher to an already booked flight.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try calling Delta and see what they say, but unfortunately Airlines are usually pretty picky on these types of things. I am certain that there is no way to do it online with an already existing reservation. Who knows? Maybe you will get a really nice agent on the phone who can pull some strings!